# How can I delete all rows before a certain timestamp in a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
                                     columnA     columnB
symbol  timestamp                         
AAPL    2022-08-17 16:49:38.857000
AAPL    2022-08-17 16:49:48.869000
AAPL    2022-08-17 16:50:10.524000

TSLA    2022-08-17 16:49:40.575000
TSLA    2022-08-17 16:49:50.346000
TSLA    2022-08-17 16:50:10.728000
```

How can I remove all rows before `15:50:00` for only one symbol, say `AAPL`

I tried this:

```
multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[symbol], list_of_timestamps])
df.drop(multi,inplace=True)
```

But it sometimes throws me the following error:

```
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 623, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_indexer
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 603, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine._extract_level_codes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3442, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Is there a simpler way to remove all rows before 16:50:00 for AAPL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```py
df.query("symbol != 'AAPL' or timestamp < '2022-08-17 16:50:00'")
```